# What's a better way to swap two argument values?

Tags: javascript

So given a function

```
function foo( a, b ) {

}
```

Now, if I wanted to swap the values of the arguments `a` and `b`, I could write this:

```
var t = a;
a = b;
b = t;
```

However, this is an ugly pattern - it requires three statements (three lines of code), plus a local variable. Now, I could bear three statements, but having to declare that annoying helper variable? I would like to avoid that.

So, what would be a better way to do this? (Better as in fewer lines of code (possibly one-liner), or not declaring a local variable.)

I came up with this:

```
(function ( t ) { a = b; b = t; })( a ); // swap a and b
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/J9T22/

So, what can you come up with?

Comment: Aren't `a` and `b` now the same value in the first example? (And isn't this like code golf?)

Comment: In your second code block shouldn't it say `b = t` ?

Comment: *However, this is an ugly pattern - it requires three statements (three lines of code), plus a local variable.* - Ummmm... huh?  Ugly?!  Doesn't get much more simple and straightforward then that!  Don't worry, after let some more time pass and you will stop being so concerned with producing terse and less readable code.  We all go through it.

Comment: your idea isn't useful since in your case a and b are local variables, which will simply get destroyed, and since you can't pass in the variable's addresses (so that the function can augment their value) it's something of a nonstarter.

Comment: @EdS. I'd rather not pollute my local scope with a lame temporary variable. Thank you, Sir.

Comment: Right, because `(function ( t ) { a = b; b = t; })( a );` is far more easily understood and maintained.

Comment: @EdS. That's why you have the side-comment. So, there aren't readability concerns.

Comment: Haha, yes, comments are always the solution for convoluted code!  Your #1 goal should be writing code that *doesn't require comments at all*.  Comments only where absolutely needed, and please, don't write a swap function that requires comments...ever.

Comment: @EdS. Ah, don't exaggerate. This is fairly easy to understand. Popular scripts, like jQuery, do far more convoluted stuff.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Because they *need* to, not because they want to avoid declaring a variable when that would be the simplest and most straightforward solution.  Anyway, I think you get where I stand on this, I'll bow out now.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel No, `a` and `b` are not local variables of that nested function. They are the actual arguments. So, it works fine.

Comment: ah, I see, you're working on the above as globals. In that case you're drastically over complicating without any benefit. The ONLY goal here (if there is any, and it's arguable that there isn't) is to eliminate the third variable. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel No, no, they're not globals either `:)`. I would never do that, and besides, implicit globals throw in strict mode. They are arguments of the outer function. So, the nested function won't find them in itself, so it'll step out into the outer scope (the scope of the outer function) and find them there defined as arguments.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, typo, I corrected it. No, I wouldn't call it code golf. Length-wise, it's the same. I'm merely using a function expression to avoid the local variable. Code golf would be the second answer below (`a=[b][b=a,0];`).

Comment: @Šime, yeah, I understand, I don't mean global to the page, I just mean global to outside this function. Obviously I have no idea what the wrapper around the displayed code is, so, I'm using the term global generically.

Comment: _"polluting the local namespace with a temporary variable"_ - It is _not_ "polluting" to declare a local function variable, whether it is temporary or not - are you really going to write functions so long and complicated that you lose track of what `t` is for? If so, name it `temporarySwap` or something. Using a local variable like that lets you implement your requirement in the most straightforward manner.

Comment: @nnnnnn I made a mistake in my question. The variable is not temporary, since local variables cannot be deleted. But I do think of it as pollution. Ok, maybe pollution is not the best term. It's an annoyance. I just want to swap two values, and if I have to declare an entire new variable just to do that, then that's an annoyance. And since JavaScript is such an hack-friendly language, I thought I'd just put it out there, and see what creative solutions people come up with - and they didn't disappoint me `:)`

Comment: Well I agree it is interesting as a learning exercise, but I wouldn't want to see any of these other solutions outside the classroom...

Comment: All this heated discussion and nobody suggested a simple higher-order function, `flip`, to handle this? It's got some very real use cases (e.g. for creating composeLeft/pipe from compose, `var pipe = flip(compose)`). See my answer below

Answer (score 14):

Using a function for it? **Seriously?**

The easiest is often the best:

```
var t = a;
a = b;
b = t;
```

If you use it e.g. for server-side JS (i.e. you only need to support *one* JavaScript engine) you might also be able to use the destructuring assignment syntax:

```
[a, b] = [b, a]
```

Comment: @Petah `delete t` has *no effect* in ES3 implementations, and will *throw* a `SyntaxError` *exception* in ES 5.x Strict Mode (`"use strict";`), because variable identifiers are names of properties of the Variable Object with the `DontDelete` attribute (ES3) or names of mutable but not configurable declaration bindings in the VariableEnvironment record of the execution context (ES 5.x).

Answer (score 8):

This is a fun little exercise.

You could do this: `a=[b][b=a,0]`

```
var a='a';
var b='b';
a=[b][b=a,0];
alert(a + ', ' + b); // "b, a"
```

Also +1 from me, ignore the haters ;)

...Oh wait! Is this *not* a fun little exercise, but actually for real-world use? Then you'd better not do it this way, because it's less readable than var t=a;a=b;b=t!

```
a=[b][b=a,0];      // wth?
var t=a; a=b; b=t; // ahhh so readable!
```

But no, seriously, doing it this way actually gives you neat benefits over having to create another variable, because you can do it in line. Var declarations can't usually be part of normal statements, so attempting to do something like `(var t=a; a=b; b=t)` will just throw a SyntaxError, but  `(a=[b][b=a,0])` evaluates to `a`, which could be useful.

It's interesting to discuss things like this because, while doing things in unconventional ways may not be welcome in our production code, it is a great way to learn about the language. And that (I think) is what SO is all about. I rest my case.

Comment: can you explain what's happening?

Comment: i'm storing the value of b in an array, assigning the value of a to b, and assigning a the value in the first (only) array element where we stored b. When you see commas used like this, the whole set of comma'd expressions evaluates to whatever the last one evaluates to, in this case, 0.

Comment: @user886931 Now, that is some advanced stuff. Did you just come up with this, or did you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw something similar if not identical on cljs a few years ago. But it makes sense if you think about it... the b=a assignment can't happen until b is stored in the array :)

Comment: @user886931 Yes, once you figure it out `:)` It uses an anonymous array object to store the reference to one of the arguments. This is really clever.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about comma separated expressions before, thanks!

Comment: Do not forget that alerting `a` works only because you are concatenating with a string literal. `a` still refers to an `Array` instance, while `b` truly stores a `Number` value.

Comment: PointedEars, no, it's a primitive... `a` isn't assigned to the whole array, just element 0. Test it out :) Ed: what function? This is for doing it inline, wouldn't be any use in a function in a language like js.

Comment: ThiefMaster: It answers the question instead of evading it. It's nearly as readable as destructuring. a=b, b=a. I could just as easily downvote your answer for ignoring basic conditions set forth in the question (no additional local variables, as few lines as possible) but I won't, because that's the kind of thing people do when they get upset because someone else answered a question in a way they couldn't.

Comment: Edit suggestion so that code becomes better readable and understandable.

Comment: PointedEars I probably should, but it seems silly to spend my time trying to explain/defend this solution to what was clearly intended as a fun little exercise or experiment, esp. to someone who clearly missed the point. Unless I missed the point, and the OP actually wanted something for real-world use. But I doubt it.

Answer (score 5):

In Mozilla's [Javascript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Avoiding_temporary_variables) you could do `[a, b] = [b, a]`.

Comment: Not yet available in most browsers

Comment: +1, while not commonly available that's the most appropriate way if your code runs in an environment where you know it's supported (e.g. server-side js)

Answer (score 3):

I've read that you should never do this but...

```
a=5;
b = 7
//add parenthesis to make this do what it should in one line
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

They should now have each other's values.
[edit] as per pointedears' description this doesn't work as stated, but here's the description of how it DOES work... however, as already stated (by others) stick to what's simplest. there's no reason to do this, you will NOT notice any performance gains, and your code will simply become less readable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

and here it is in action...
http://jsfiddle.net/nHdwH/

Comment: Assumes that we are always dealing with integers.

Comment: You should have tested this. Afterwards, `a === 0` and `b === 5`. This is rather unsurprising because: `var a = 5; var b = 7;
a ^= b ^= a ^= b;` ~
`var a = 5; var b = 7; a = a ^ (b = b ^ (a = a ^ b));` ~
`a = 5 ^ (b = 7 ^ (a = 5 ^ 7));` ~
`a = 5 ^ (b = 7 ^ (a = 2));` ~
`a = 5 ^ (b = 5);` ~
`a = 5 ^ 5;` ~
`a = 0;`

Comment: I remember doing this in school 20 years ago in C... I didn't test it because the first thing I said was "you should never do this" for a host of obvious reasons. If I got the syntax wrong, you have my humblest apologies, I know it's possible in some VERY similar way... but still you shouldn't do it! :)

Comment: @PointedEars Ah yes, of course. I totally see it when I look at those 3 lines of code. `:P`

Comment: Works. +1 for interesting solution and references. (It's _PointedEars_, though).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Blame SO for not allowing more formatting in comments. You can copy-paste it, and consider `~` a line delimiter. Then it becomes obvious. HTH.

Comment: @PointedEars I was being sarcastic `:)`. My experience with bitwise operations is pretty slim, so the above code is like Chinese.

Comment: sorry PointedEars... Didn't mean to insult you with my misuse of your handle. :) it was inadvertent.

Answer (score 3):

If you're allowing for [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29) only, or [future ES6 stuff](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adestructuring), you can use destructuring assignment:

```
[a,b] = [b,a]
```

---

If the biggest concern is variable environment pollution, you could borrow the `arguments` object.

```
arguments[arguments.length] = a;
a = b;
b = arguments[arguments.length];
```

But this gets a bit long.

---

Or you could assign an object to an existing parameter:

```
a = {a:a,b:b};
b = a.a;
a = a.b;
```

---

```
function foo( a, b ) {
    a = {a:a,b:b};
    b = a.a;
    a = a.b;
    console.log(a,b);  'baz' 'bar'
}

foo('bar','baz');
```

---

Or eliminate a like like this:

```
a = {b:b,a:(b=a)};
a = a.b;
```

---

Or down to one line:

```
a = {b:b,a:(b=a)}.b;
```

---

Currently in "strict mode" supported implementations, you can do this *(if you're actually running in "strict mode")*:

```
a = b; b = arguments[0];
```

This is because changes to *formal parameters* has no effect on the `arguments` object, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, we can start using that in 2020... `:/`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: You can start using it today depending on your targeted environment.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: If your main concern is polluting the variable environment, you could borrow the `arguments` object, though it will take quite a few characters.

Comment: Actually, just `a = {b:b,a:(b=a)}.b;`. Well, we can't ignore all versions of IE...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: `a = {b:b,a:(b=a)}.b` Yep, that's my last version. but are you saying it doesn't work in IE?

Comment: I mean the destructuring assignments. We can expect that feature in IE11 somewhere around 2013 I guess. From then, we'll have to give IE10 at least 1-2 years to catch on (to build a market share). And then, only then...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Oh yeah, like I said it depends on your targeted environment. Some code is written for specific targets. The way Google is working on some ES6 features right now, I wouldn't be surprised if we could use it in NodeJS before long.

Comment: `arguments` is available only in local context, and [might become unconfigurable in the next Edition of ECMAScript](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:arguments_array_as_array). Do not reuse.

Comment: @PointedEars Well, arguments only appear in local context, don't they? `:P`

Comment: @PointedEars: Yeah, that would be specific to argument swapping. But that reminds me that currently in strict mode, it's even easier. `a = b; b = arguments[0];` since changes to parameters has no effect on the arguments object, and vice versa. Added to answer.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: So which browsers are you actually supporting? If IE9 has strict mode implemented properly, my latest update should work there as well.

Comment: ...oops, looks like IE9 doesn't support "strict mode" at all. At least according to the Kangax compatibility table.

Comment: @RightSaidFred Yes, unfortunately. It works in the other browsers though. My list of reasons why I hate IE is getting cramped `:/`

Comment: @RightSaidFred Btw, I don't actually need to support anything (I don't do commercial sites or sites for the general public). As a matter of fact, on my W3 Viewer, I redirect IE8 visitors to GetFirefox.com.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I love the viewer! Just bookmarked it. Good question too. It's been a fun exercise.

Comment: @RightSaidFred Well spotted (ES 5.1, section 10.6, note 1). But you should say "strict mode-supporting *implementations*" instead.  It is *JScript 5.x*, not IE, that is not supporting Strict Mode, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> What's a better way to swap two argument values?

There is no "better" way, only a number of progressively more obscure and confusing ways.

Some people might view those other methods as "clever", and I guess some of them are, but I wouldn't want to work with anybody who thinks they're actually "better" because I would not want to see such methods cropping up in real project code.

The "clever" maths methods only work if you assume integer values, so in my opinion they're wrong since you didn't specify types.

If you find the three statements ugly you could do this:

```
var t;
t = a, a = b, b = t;
```

Yes it's virtually the same thing, but at least it puts the swap code all on the same line.

(Having said all that, I think `[a, b] = [b, a];` would be "better" if not for the lack of browser support for it.)

Answer (score 0):

If the values are integers, then you can use arithmetic to do the work:

```
function foo( a, b ) {
    a = -(b = (a += b) - b) + a;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}

foo(1,2);
```

See http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=265

Comment: Oh god... please don't.  Actually there are much cooler ways of swapping in place using binary arithmetic... but still... don't.

Comment: Bad idea. ECMAScript implementations use 32-bit integer arithmetic only for binary operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[a,b];
b=a[0];
a=a[1];
```

this uses only the variables a and b, but it creates an array, 
which is more significant than a temporary variable.

Use the temporary variable.

var t=a;
a=b;
b=t;

Another upvote for sanity.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly disagree with other people, it can be useful.  However, defining it inline is bad, bad, bad, bad, bad. If you are going to do it, it should be a higher order function:

```
function flip(fn) {
  return function(a, b) {
     return fn.call(null, b, a);
  };
}
```

For example:

```
function log() {
   console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}

flip(log)(1, 2); // 2 1
```

Now this might seem silly, but this kind of stuff happens quite often when you're mapping/reducing/iterating etc. Say you have some function:

```
function doSomeStuff(index, value) {
  // complex stuff happening here
}
```

And an array:

```
var arr = ["foo", "bar", "etc"];
```

If you were to use, for example, map on this array and needed to call `doSomeStuff` you'd have to hand roll this function:

```
arr.map(function(value, index) {
  return doSomeStuff(index, value);
});
```

Whilst you could say this isn't bad, it is distracting from what you're trying to do (just call the damn function!). With this higher order function it can be reduced to:

```
arr.map(flip(doSomeStuff));
```

If you wanted a more complete flip function you could:

```
function flip(fn) {
  return function() {
     var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
     return fn.apply(null, args.reverse());
  };
}
```

And now:

```
flip(log)(1,2,3,4,5); // 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume in the real world one would want this swap to be conditional.

```
[a,b] = c? [a,b] : [b,a]
```

You could also replace all instances of a with [a,b][+c] and all b's with  [b,a][+c] like:

```
arr.sort( (a,b) => [a,b][+c] - [b,a][+c] )
```

or just have a function to call the function:

```
swapMyFunction = (a,b) => myFunction(b,a)
```