# How does [b][b = a,0] swap between a and b?

Tags: javascript

As [gdoron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864059/283863) pointed out,

```
var a = "a";
var b = "b";

a = [b][b = a,0];
```

Will swap `a` and `b`, and although it looks a bit of *hacky*, it has triggered my curiosity and I am very curious at how it works. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: _"a bit of hacky"_??? a lot of hacky... :-)

Comment: Relevant: [What's a better way to swap two argument values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482402/whats-a-better-way-to-swap-two-argument-values)

Comment: Wouldn't it have made more sense to comment on godron's other answer and ask for clarification in your original question?

Comment: @FelixKling. I suggested him to ask it in other question. comments are not the place of questions-answers. And it's not just clarification of the answer, it's totally different question (In my humble opinion!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var a = "a";
var b = "b";

a = [b][b = a, 0];
```

Let's break the last line into pieces:

```
[b]       // Puts b in an array - a safe place for the swap.
[b = a]   // Assign a in b
[b = a,0] // Assign a in b and return the later expression - 0 with the comma operator.
```

so finally it is `a =[b][0]` - the first object in the `[b]` array => `b` assigned to `a`

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr7hJ/1/)

read @am not I am comments in this question:
[When is the comma operator useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9579546/601179)
It's his code...

Comment: So when `b` is put in the array, it is safe?

Comment: @Derek. It's not going lost when `b = a`

Answer (score 1):

It might help (or hinder) to think of it terms of the semantically equivalent lambda construction (here, parameter `c` takes the place of element 0):

```
a = (function(c) { b = a; return c; })(b);
```